# regexp flag x doesn't work for me

Tags: ruby, regex

What's wrong with my regex?

```
DATE_REGEX = /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/
def x_flag_testing
  str = "Service Date: 2/5/2016 to 15/6/2016"
  regex = /service date:\s+
          (?<start_date>#{DATE_REGEX})\s+to\s+
          (?<end_date>#{DATE_REGEX})/ix
  binding.pry
  puts str[regex, :start_date]
end
```

I'm trying to:
[image]

and get nil result!
To show that my regex works fine in one line and without x flag:
[image]

Comment: 1. Please paste your code as plain text. 2. Please share `DATE_REGEX` const.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because the literal space between "service" and "date" is ignored (because of the `x` flag).

Change it to a `\s+`:

```
/service\s+date:\s+.../ix
```